# UniqueEntity is removed after sync

Tags: symfony, doctrine

If I add [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html), and make some changes in DB and after it

**Do**

1. mapping import
2. Convert annotation
3. generate entities

I lost information about uniqueentity in my entity.php
(I have the same problem when I add `constructor` function to my entity)
**How to fix it?**

Comment: What do you mean by 'lost information about uniqueentity'? Like the validator doesn't work to ensure only on 'entity' in your database has that particular value for the entity's property?

Comment: @AndrewNolan Lines which I added about `construct` or `uniqueentity` are removed

Answer (score 0):

When you generate entities with Doctrine this way, it will completely regenerate your class from scratch.  It uses a skeleton to build this class, and does not try to smartly merge any of your previous code.  It does make a backup of the file in the `Entity` directory though.  So after regenerating you should see this:

```
Entity.php
Entity.php~
```

You can just open up the backup file and copy/paste your custom code back into the new file.  It's always good to make a backup of your existing Entity directory before regenerating all of them if you've made a lot of custom changes.  Or, if you're simply adding a new column or changing some things, you can also just manually edit your Entity rather than regenerating it completely.